# Novel about a girl living in submarine, becomes fish if water touches her?

Tags: story-identification, novel, shape-shifter

There is this girl, who lived all of her life in a submarine where her and other teens, the crew, don't age. They also can't go out, because if the sea water touches you, you become a huge fish and with time you forget who you are.

So she investigates, I think, with a friend of hers. They end up in a boat, then a big ship. She finds out if she jumps from a high tree she can grow feathers and can fly (I think?).

There are many things I don't remember, but in the end she had became a fish with her friend, then they found an island and turned back human again, but with blue skin.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a distorted memory of *Ponyo* -- was that based on a book?

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for the [Sigrid et les Mondes perdus](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigrid_et_les_Mondes_perdus) (in French) saga.

Your question points to the first book, [L'Œil de la Pieuvre](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16092761-l-oeil-de-la-pieuvre?from_search=true) :

Sigrid belongs to the BlueDeep's crew, a giant submarine that travels around an ocean planet called Almoha. The water is magical in essence, and anyone getting wet will be turned into a giant fish.

I don't exactly remember the whole story, but I recall the female character having blue hair, and that her age would change abruptly (looking 13 years old a moment and 20 years old the next).